# Select current value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, grails

Hello I have this dropdown menu,how can I select the current selected value and assign it to variable and if nothing is selected assing null?

```
  <select name="emplStatus2" onchange="swapFieldsets(this.value, '#sa-email', '#sa-password') " class="form-control" id="emplStatus2">
 <option value="Home">Send via Home Email</option>
  <option value="Business">Send via Business Email</option>
<option value="Password">Set a password now,provide access information offline</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: [duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: There  you go edited :)

Comment: Add id to select tag, document.getElementById("SELECTID").value

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<select name="emplStatus2" onchange="swapFieldsets(this.value, '#sa-email', '#sa-password') " class="form-control" id="emplStatus2">
  <option value="Home">Send via Home Email</option>
  <option value="Business">Send via Business Email</option>
  <option value="Password">Set a password now,provide access information offline</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

Getting value using javaScript

```
<script>
  // Method-1
  var selVal = document.getElementById("emplStatus2");
  alert(selVal.options[selVal.selectedIndex].value);

  // store value in veriable
  var val = selVal.options[selVal.selectedIndex].value;

 // Method-2
 var selVal = document.getElementById("emplStatus2").value;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="emplStatus2" onchange="swapFieldsets(this.value, '#sa-email', '#sa-password') " class="form-control" id="emplStatus2">
  <option value="Home">Send via Home Email</option>
  <option value="Business">Send via Business Email</option>
  <option value="Password">Set a password now,provide access information offline</option>
</select>
```

Use can use jquery or javascript script to get selected value:

Jquery :

```
   var selectedValues = $("#emplStatus2").val();
    console.log(selectedValues);
```

or if you want to select text

```
var selectedValue = $("#emplStatus2 option:selected").text();
```